# MIGS Payment Gateway Integration

Tags: magento2, payment-gateway

I want to use MIGS 3rd party Hosted Solution to our magento 2 integration but 
I am getting 400 response code error from http://migs.mastercard.com.au/vpcpay

I configured only MerchantId to send payment request. Moreover, there are two other options in the extension configuration namely 1) Secure Secret 2) Access Code. But our Bank denies to use it and replied, it will work with only MerchantId.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is there any free extension for that MIGS ?

Answer (score 0):

**Look Up Your Access Code and Secure Hash Secret in Merchant Administration**

You need your Virtual Payment Client Access Code and Secure Hash Secret before
starting your integration:

- **Access Code**

The access code uniquely authenticates a merchant and the Merchant ID on the
Payment Server.

- **Secure Hash Secret only**

The Secure Hash Secret is a key used as the initial piece of encryption data to create
a Secure Hash. This ensures transaction data is not tampered with while in transit to
the Virtual Payment Client.

Your access code and secure hash secret can be found in Merchant Administration on
the Configuration Details page of the Admin menu option.

To retrieve your Access Code and Secure Hash Secret:

1. Ask your Payment Service Provider for your MSO ID and log in
   details. Login to the new Merchant Administration website as
   Administrator: https://migs.mastercard.com.au/ma/
2. Select **Admin > Operators**.
3. Click on the Create a new Merchant Administration Operator link.
   Ensure that you enable **Modify the merchant configuration.**
4. Click Submit.
5. Logout, then login again as the new Operator.
6. Select **Admin > Configuration Details.**

You will see the **Access Code** and **Secure Hash Secret**.